# Customer Cheating Paypal API deleting table items. (CFML)

Tags: coldfusion, paypal-adaptive-payments

I just had a customer go through some extensive steps in order to delete items prior to submitting the html form to try and avoid/delete line items that pertain to shipping. What they did was in the inspection part of chrome the opened the table and deleted the line items so when it transferred to Paypal they did not show up.

My question is how do I go about preventing this, I know they spent some time trying to figure it out.

The site is written mostly in CFML as I have a pretty good understanding from a previous job of mine, but I am having issues and want to prevent this from happening in the future.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Validate the order server-side (including shipping calculations) before sending it off to PayPal. Did you note this customer? This is pretty much digital shoplifting. At the very least, this customer should be marked and banned.

Comment: Yeah this is where it gets a little confusing to me... I was trying to use JS to validate but having the line items with the counter variable of #i# I cannot put that into the JS

Comment: Don't do primary validation on the client with JS. It can be turned off. Or even worse, be manipulated to calculate your shipping at $-1000. Client-side validation is meant to help the user. Important stuff should be handled inside your system where you have control of the data.

Comment: With my item build like below, how do I go about checking them?<input type="hidden" name="item_name_#s#" value="#thisRow.FishName#,#thisRow.FishSex#,#thisRow.FishSize#,Qty=#thisRow.Quantity#">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_#s#" value="#LineTotal#">

Comment: All `<input>` fields will be submitted with the form. So on your ColdFusion page where the page is submitted, dump the `form` scope; `<cfdump var="#form#">`. That will show you all of the data being passed. You can use those variables to validate all of the data.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="amount_#s#` - And do not use/trust any currency values submitted from the client side since those too can be manipulated, not just omitted.

Comment: Yeah I was passing the information in hidden fields. What I'm currently doing in the mean time is passing them to another form when they click, hiding the div and then using an auto submit .